# Salesforce Maps - How to create a custom action button in Actions shape layer

Tags: visual-workflow

As business requirements, we are very interested in Salesforce Maps functionalities, but as we have seen from now, it doesn't allow for very much customization excepts the data visualization main scope.

We want to have more power on the tools offered, and one cool feature would be to create a shape layer and then by an action button call a lwc/flow/invocable method that it's possible to pass parameters in input (the geoJson of the shape would be great).

Do you know if it's possible to achieve this level of customization? because as I have seen so far, a custom action can be created only on the marker layer and not in the shape.

Thanks for any advise!